# Reduce Byte Array from document scanning

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am tasked on reducing the size amount of a byte array when a VB/C# based solution as the solution was written originally not to taking in account any scanner brand/type/etc but currently raw image are exceeding 3MB per pages.

I was recommended to check LEADTOOLS SDKs but I believe that I shouldn't try on any paid solution yet, as I see that LEADTOOLS is complete package and might be an expensive overkill & more importantly, I want to avoid changing massively the code, specially re-write.

This is how currently the image scanning conversion to byte array looks like:

```
Private Shared Function ConvertImageToByteArray(ByVal imageToConvert As System.Drawing.Image, ByVal formatOfImage As Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As Byte()
    Dim Ret As Byte()
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
        imageToConvert.Save(ms, formatOfImage)
        Ret = ms.ToArray()
    End Using
    Return Ret
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: 7/27/2022 - 2:48 - Correcting spelling*

Comment: If the scans are of something like text or line drawings and there are large areas of pure colour, PNG might be suitable as it compresses the data without loss. If [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) is acceptable, saving using JPEG compression could give less data.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is assumed that the documentation are mainly paper works but some graphics like customer's logo on documentation template are expected.

We have applied a 3MB limit and heavy graphics as testing or paper works with much pen writing goes beyond that.

Comment: I suggest that you try saving example scans using a program such as Photoshop, GIMP, Affinity Photo, or any other which gives you plenty of options and see which file format and compression settings give an acceptable result. Then find out how to use those in your own program. There is no magic "do this" answer for the question as presented; for example: reducing the resolution of the scans to 256x256 pixels in 8-bit colour will easily fulfil the less-than-3MB criterion.

Comment: Since you mentioned LEADTOOLS, there are 4 tips I can give you. First, the [free evaluation](https://leadtools.com/downloads) lets you fully test the image compression (and other features) of the SDK before you decide to buy. Second, there are dozens of image formats supported by the entry-level [Imaging Pro SDK](https://leadtools.com/sdk/products/imaging-pro), so if you decide to buy, you probably won’t need the more advanced (more expensive) SDKs. Third, the C#/VB code to use the toolkit is rather easy to write. And fourth, there’s free email and chat support during the free evaluation.